# Como filtrar dados em um data.frame usando um determinado período de tempo no R?

Tags: r, data, data.frame

Suponhamos que tenho um `data.frame` com quatro colunas:

```
print(Dados)

CLIENTE QTDE VALOR$ DATA_COMPRA
1234    2    50     2019-02-04
4586    1    70     2019-01-17
6535    3    25     2018-12-28
9562    1    150    2018-12-25
3478    7    12     2018-10-12
2684    4    33     2018-06-03
1593    25   2      2017-12-31
```

Meu objetivo é filtrar os clientes que fizeram compras nos últimos 3 meses.
Os clientes que estão entre o mês 2 de 2019 e o mês 12 de 2018:

```
print(Dados_Filtrados)

CLIENTE QTDE VALOR$ DATA_COMPRA
1234    2    50     2019-02-04
4586    1    70     2019-01-17
6535    3    25     2018-12-28
9562    1    150    2018-12-25
```

Mas este `data.frame` possui a seguinte condição:

Este `data.frame` é atualizado mensalmente. Ou seja não posso filtrar pelo os três últimos nomes do mês ou por uma data específica, porque a cada atualização o mês irá se alterar.

Entendo que a solução seria filtrar o `data.frame` usando um período determinado de tempo. Mas como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Porquê o mês 2 de 2019? Isso é escolhido pelo usuário? Já estamos no mês 4, portanto não deve ser através de `Sys.Date()`.

Comment: @Rui Barradas eu especifiquei mês 2 por estar de acordo com o exemplo dos dados que coloquei, esta tabela não é real, o mês 2 de 2019 a mês 12 de 2018 foi apenas um período de exemplo. Mas se você quiser posso alterar os dados para facilitar o entendimento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função seguinte filtra os dados por data, passada como argumento `mes`. Assume-se que o formato da data é ano-mês-dia, e portanto deverá ser passada uma data completa, mas pode ser outro formato qualquer, desde que seja também passado no argumento `formato`.

```
library(lubridate)

filtrarMes <- function(DF, mes, formato = "%Y-%m-%d"){
  if(!grepl("%d", formato)){
    mes <- paste(mes, "01", sep = "-")
    formato <- paste(formato, "%d", sep = "-")
  }
  mes <- as.Date(mes, format = formato)
  prim <- mes - months(3)
  i <- which(DF[["DATA_COMPRA"]] >= prim)
  DF[i, ]
}

filtrarMes(Dados, mes = "2019-2", formato = "%Y-%m")
#  CLIENTE QTDE VALOR. DATA_COMPRA
#1    1234    2     50  2019-02-04
#2    4586    1     70  2019-01-17
#3    6535    3     25  2018-12-28
#4    9562    1    150  2018-12-25

filtrarMes(Dados, mes = Sys.Date())
#  CLIENTE QTDE VALOR. DATA_COMPRA
#1    1234    2     50  2019-02-04
#2    4586    1     70  2019-01-17
```

**Dados.**

```
Dados <- read.table(text = "
CLIENTE QTDE VALOR$ DATA_COMPRA
1234    2    50     2019-02-04
4586    1    70     2019-01-17
6535    3    25     2018-12-28
9562    1    150    2018-12-25
3478    7    12     2018-10-12
2684    4    33     2018-06-03
1593    25   2      2017-12-31
", header = TRUE)

Dados$DATA_COMPRA <- as.Date(Dados$DATA_COMPRA)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @RuiBarradas! Vou testar.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!